# How to add new attribute like tier pricing in magento product form

Tags: magento-1.7

I am working on jewel store in which **need to get the stone/diamond options with its price and need to add them to the different charges** that also will be given by admin.

Now i **need to add attribute like tier pricing box where admin can add Number of diamonds/Stones** and based on its qty/type i need to pull price from other model(Which is ok with ajax call).

Attached screenshot of how i want it(I edited it with firebug html from tier pricing)

[image]

Can anyone help me to understand how we can replicate the tier pricing block to this purpose and still tier pricing needs to work. Basically this is purely for admin UI purpose and it wont store all its values in that product attributes.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think its better to solve this with a configurable product, for every product option you need to create a simple product where you define the attributes you mention with the price. You can make the shape, color, clarity, carat weight and qty as configurable selection attributes so that the selection can be done in the frontend for the correct simple product that gives you the final price.

Comment: Yes that was our first choice and it didnt worked since we cant add that much products(its bit large store) and maintaining it is too difficult. So working on simple product based view itself.

Comment: Did you also look at the custom options on a simple product? You can also add pricing for the specified options there.

Comment: Custom options will not work for me. Am able to add tier price like attribute field in core file itself but am not able to add observer or extend it. Am working on it. Kindly advice if you used "adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_prepare_form" event before.